# Is it possible to add solidy to specified area

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to add thickness just to wedge, without separating wedge from sole? Also, why there is this ugly edge on place where sole and wedge join? It's all one mesh, there is no doubles, that's why I don't want to separate them, because there will be visible seam where they connect. [image]

[image]

Comment: This is just a bad solution, the reason for that ugly seam is simply due to your topology, your base is whole closed mesh, like simple cube and the top is just single extruded edge... This creates bad topology and shading because bot is double faces yet top is one sided... solidify is not good idea... My solution would be to extrude that top along normals inside, create new edge at the bottom part and connect it...

Comment: Yeah that sound a lot easier. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are rules that apply to Blender as in real life. You can't make a paper-thin object that's not infinitely thin. The only exceptions I know for 3d,are textures and volumetric objects that actually need to be infinitely thin as a non touchable-interactable layer. As MikoCG says making it solid is the solution and to do this you have to go the extrusion way from the top of the shoe.

Here is my take to help you. If you can see a good topology has every face connecting to another face. Making the connection between them having a perfect curve even in extreme angles. When there is no continuation it breaks the mesh.
[image]
[image]